# Limit results from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to limit the amount of results that are being returned from this AJAX call to 5. I think I could use .slice() to do this but I'm not exactly sure what way to go about it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "myurl",
    dataType: "xml",
    cache: false,
    success: parsePopular
  });
});

function parsePopular(popular) {
  $(popular).find("item").each(function() {
    $("#popularArticles").append("<h1><p class='Bold'><a href='" + $(this).find("link").text() + "'>" + $(this).find("title").text() + "</a></p></h1>");
  });
}
```

Any ideas would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: It is a **really** good idea to do this server-side. When you come to a library, you don't say "please, bring me all 977413 books. Oh, thanks, I need these 5". You say "could you, please, bring me these 5 books". It is a really important performance issue.

Comment: yes @YeldarKurmangaliyev is right, when you dont need some data, then try not sending it across network as it creates lot of issues when you start checking for performance of your pages. "Prevention is better than Cure"

Comment: Both fair points, noted and will try to do that in the future. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice and remove

```
$(popular).find('item').slice(5).remove();
```

Comment: `.slice(5)` will return all `item` having index beginning at `5` $(popular).find('item').slice(0, 5).remove();`

Comment: @guest271314 this will remove first 5 elements rather than after first 5 elements.

Comment: @guest271314 yes, it will return all elements after 5 and then remove them. Which is why your answer is right (hence upvoted) and comment is wrong since you are slicing first 5 and removing those.

Comment: This only worked for me whenever I entered -5 for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

`$(popular).find("item").slice(0, 5)`

```js
$("div").slice(0, 5).remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>0</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
```